# Cannot format a string to a duration

Tags: mysql, string, time

There is a string like this `09h 36m 18s` and I want to get something like this `09:36:18`.

I tried this query but got nothing:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("09h 36m 18s", "%H %i %s"),"%H:%i:%s")
```

How to get the desired output?

Comment: We can specify a format model that matches the input string, including the literal **h**", "**m**" and "**s**" characters to match the input string.  i.e. **`'%Hh %mm %ss'`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a string from substrings:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(':', SUBSTRING('09h 36m 18s', 1, 2)
                    , SUBSTRING('09h 36m 18s', 5, 2)
                    , SUBSTRING('09h 36m 18s', 9, 2))
```

Comment: we aren't told what input is expected. i.e. will there ever be single digit minutes or  seconds, will that have a leading zero)? will the hours never exceed two digits? this will handle input in some specific formats. but in terms of a more generalized approach, there are simpler ways that are more flexible. see the answer from @verhie

Comment: @spencer I prefer string functions for converting one string to another. But that's just me.

Comment: my preference is to handle time and duration as DATETIME and TIME datatypes respectively, and not mess with string manipulation. when we do need to convert time and duration to and from a variety of string formats, my preference is to use the MySQL builtin functions.

Comment: What should be returned, given a wonky string value such as : `' 09 h6m13 s' ` ?  is it reasonable to return `' 0:h6:3 '` ?  would it be reasonable to return `'09:06:13'` ?

Comment: @spencer it works for given input. Speaking of wonky input, does your recommended answer handle `01h 01m 60s`?

Comment: The string value `01h 01m 60s` interpreted using STR_TO_DATE yields NULL. I think the question is whether that is a reasonable return, given a malformed TIME value. It really depends on how we look at the problem space. Are we doing string manipulation? Or are we formatting a string from a TIME value? (Looking at OP original code, it looks like we are attempting to read in a TIME value, and then format it. I think the only "miss" in OP code was not including the "h", "m", and "s" literal characters in the format model.)

Answer (score 2):

I like the [suggestion by @salman-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839866/cannot-format-a-string-to-a-duration/58840071#answer-58839935) and would use it anytime [`regex_replace` suggested by @tim-biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839866/cannot-format-a-string-to-a-duration/58840071#answer-58840001) is not available.

For another option, to give you flexibility, you can do *bad algebra* and power your way through it with `replace`.

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace('09h 36m 18s', ' ', ':'), 'h', ''), 'm', ''), 's', '');
```

The basic syntax of string Replace in MySQL is as shown below [(read more)](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/mysql-replace-function/):

```
SELECT REPLACE (Expression, Change_String, Replace_String) FROM Source
```

Comment: This is clever and I like it +1.

Comment: note that if the input has single digit for minute or second, with a space in place of leading zero e.g. `09h  6m  8s`  this will produce output like `09::6::8`. Not entirely clear from the example given what values we should expect, but for more flexibility, we might want to replace the h, m and s with the colon, and remove the spaces.

Comment: @spencer7593 - regex is always the way to go. if the OP had not put in `09` as his example, i would not have suggested it at all.  seeing that, it was a somewhat _safer_ assumption that what was being parsed includes leading zeros in all positions.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell MySQL what chars are in the provided string:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("09h 36m 18s", "%Hh %im %ss"),"%H:%i:%s");
```

Comment: this is the simplest approach +10  (this will also handle a variety of input formats,  for example for `' 09h  6 m  8s '` this expression will produce `09:06:08'`.  some of the string parsing approaches will produce different results. (not at all clear why this answer was downvoted.)

Comment: i take back my comment on regex "always" being the way to go.  this seems pretty strong to me. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `REGEXP_REPLACE` comes in handy here:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '09h 36m 18s' AS ts
)

SELECT
    ts AS ts_in,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(ts, '^([0-9]{2})h ([0-9]{2})m ([0-9]{2})s$', '$1:$2:$3') AS ts_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo